# Legend in ggplot2 - using factor labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the `interactions` package to make an interaction plot from my regression.

```
figure6 <- interact_plot(sitc0.logit, pred = lnlaggdpp, 
modx = inter_industry, interval = TRUE) + 
scale_x_continuous(name = "Economic Size (ln GDP)", breaks=seq(4,16.1,1)) + 
scale_y_continuous(name = "Probability of sanctions busting", breaks=seq(0,.5,.025)) + 
theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + 
labs(title="Marginal Effects of Intra- and Inter-Industry Trade, Agricultural Goods") + 
geom_line(aes(colour = inter_industry))
```

This is what I get when I run the above code:

[image: Interaction Plot]

I've spent the last couple of hours trying to get the legend to display correctly. The "0" and the "1" are values of a factor variable called `inter_industry`. Rather than show the levels as numbers, I want it to say "Inter-Industry" where there's the "0" and "Intra-Industry" where there's the "1."

I feel like this must be an easy fix, but I can't for the life of me get it to work! And I have 9 of these graphs to make, so it'd be nice if I could display them correctly. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Can you provide data in a reproducible form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
scale_fill_discrete(name = "", labels = c("Inter-Industry", "Intra-Industry"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I also just added value labels to my variables, which worked, too! Thanks for your help, @TarJae!